# can " if (x == checked)" work in this case?

Tags: c#

Here's my current code

```
 if (AppSettings.Settings.beta == checked);
            {
                label9.Text = "beta";
            }
```

Of course this error's, How would i go about writing this? Keep in mind that "AppSettings.Settings.beta" is being called and declared from another file (my settings file)

Comment: Probably is _AppSettings.Settings.beta == true_ But how is defined that beta property in the Settings file?

Comment: Check the datatype of beta variable.

Comment: The `checked` keyword is something completely unrelated, look it up.

Comment: @Steve Derp! That was it haha! i forgot that my value can be called by a state of true or false within that file ... silly me.. thanks!